# Listen Button in Fragment A from Fragment B

Tags: javascript, android, fragment, onclicklistener

So I want to listen `Test2` button in `fragment_blank_fragment2` from inside `fragment_terminal`. This code is not work for me. is that possible to do something like this?

```js
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_terminal, container, false);
View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment2, container, false);
View sendBtn2 = view2.findViewById(R.id.test2);
sendBtn2.setOnClickListener(v -> send("Test2"));
View sendBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.test);
sendBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> send("Test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly in fragment_terminal, you need to create a setter method that takes View.OnClickListener object and then you can use this object to set as clickListener test2 button as follows

```
public void setTest2ClickListener(@NonNull View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
        test2Button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}
```

- Inside your fragment_blank_fragment2 create a getter to return View.OnClickListener that used to handle  testButton clickListener as follows:

```
@NonNull
    public View.OnClickListener getTest2ClickListener() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //TODO implement here
            }
        };
    }
```

- Then in the activity that shows those fragments use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag")` to find both fragments then call the setter in fragment_terminal with the return value of the getter in fragment_blank_fragment2 to set the listener.
  That's a way of implementing it.